# Test a usecase with multiple coroutines (withContext and suspend) does not fail where expected

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, coroutine

I created an instrumental test for a use case which has two coroutines, before fetching data and after. I run a test on the usecase but the test passes before the suspend function is done.

Usecase:

```
class FetchAllUseCase : Observable<FetchAllUseCase.Listener>() {
 
     interface Listener {
         fun onFetched(obj: List<Obj>)
     }
 
     fun fetchObjs() {
        
         GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
             withContext(NonCancellable) {
                 val objs: List<Obj> = getObjs()
                 notify(objs)
             }
         }
     }
 
     private suspend fun notify(objs: List<Objs>) {
         withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
             for(listener in listeners){
                 listener.onFetched(objs)
             }
         }
     }
 
 
    private fun getObjss(): List<Obj> {
       /// fetch objects functionality
 
 }
```

Test:

```
class FetchAllUseCase Test: FetchAllUseCase .Listener {

    private lateinit var fetchAllUseCase: FetchAllUseCase



    @Before
    fun setUp() {
     
        fetchAllUseCase = FetchAllUseCase()
        fetchAllUseCase.registerListener(this)
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        fetchAllUseCase.unregisterListener(this)
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @Test
    fun fetchObjss()= runBlocking{

        fetchAllUseCase.fetchObjs()
    }

    override fun onFetched(objs: List<Objs>) {
     fail() //does not fail the test
    }
}
```

Test already passes before `onFetched()` is called.
`fail()` or any other `assertEquals` that should fail the test does not affect the test result.
If I run the test on the MainActivity , adding:

```
@Rule
  @JvmField
  val mMainActivityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)
```

I will get a message "Process crashed" , but the test already passed.

If I remove both coroutines, the test works as expected, i.e fails.

I tried `runBlocking, runBlockingTest, TestCoroutineDispatcher`
None solved the issue so far

Answer (score 0):

1. Add Dispatchers as Dependencies

```
class FetchAllUseCase(
    private val mainDispatcher : CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Main,
    private val ioDispatcher : CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO,

    ) : Observable<FetchAllUseCase.Listener>() {

    interface Listener {
        fun onFetched(obj: List<Obj>)
    }

    fun fetchObjs() {

        GlobalScope.launch(ioDispatcher) {
            withContext(NonCancellable) {
                val objs: List<Obj> = getObjs()
                notify(objs)
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun notify(objs: List<Objs>) {
        withContext(mainDispatcher) {
            for(listener in listeners){
                listener.onFetched(objs)
            }
        }
    }


    private fun getObjss(): List<Obj> {
        /// fetch objects functionality

    }
```

2. Testing, Inject The TestCoroutineDispatcher and use runBlockingTest

```
class FetchAllUseCase Test: FetchAllUseCase .Listener {

    private lateinit var fetchAllUseCase: FetchAllUseCase
    private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()



    @Before
    fun setUp() {

        fetchAllUseCase = FetchAllUseCase(testDispatcher,testDispatcher)
        fetchAllUseCase.registerListener(this)
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        fetchAllUseCase.unregisterListener(this)
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @Test
    fun fetchObjss()= runBlockingTest{

        fetchAllUseCase.fetchObjs()
    }

    override fun onFetched(objs: List<Objs>) {
        fail() //does not fail the test
    }
```

> If This Didn't work checkout this link [Kotlin Coroutines in Android — Unit Test](https://medium.com/swlh/kotlin-coroutines-in-android-unit-test-28ff280fc0d5)